# Using Guzzle for OpenSSL authentication

Tags: php, authentication, ssl, openssl, guzzle

Hopefully someone can help me here. I'm developing a website in the UK that needs to post properties to Zoopla and Prime Location. I'm using this facility (# shows the security required) https://realtime-listings.webservices.zpg.co.uk/docs/latest/documentation.html#security

HTTP/Authentication stuff like this an area I struggle with so I would love it if someone is able to get me up and running.

Basically I've followed all the steps mentioned on the above page and I am now in possession of a certificate returned and signed from them. What I'm struggling with is configuring Guzzle to authenticate and use this API. I have a private.pem file and a signed.crt file (that they have given).

My best attempt so far is:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([ 'exceptions' => false ]);
$request = $client->get('https://realtime-listings-api.webservices.zpg.co.uk/sandbox/v1/listing/list', array(), array(
    'cert'      => '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mywebsite/signed.crt',
    //'ssl_key'   => '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mywebsite/private.pem'
));
var_dump($request->getBody());
```

But this just gives me an error of:

> cURL error 35: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to realtime-listings-api.webservices.zpg.co.uk:443 (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

This whole concept is new to me, so if anyone is able to offer some assistance to get me connected I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

That listing ONLY supports `TLS v1.2` so you need to tell your Guzzle client about it:

```
$request = $client->get('https://realtime-listings-api.webservices.zpg.co.uk/sandbox/v1/listing/list', array(), array(
    'cert'      => '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mywebsite/signed.crt',
    'ssl_key'   => '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mywebsite/private.pem',
    'curl.options' => array(
        'CURLOPT_SSLVERSION' => 'CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2',
    )
));
```

You also need to include both your cert and SSL key when making a request to them.

Finally, they require that you provide a copy of the public.csr file you generated to them in order to validate your requests: [This is the link they provided to upload your csr](https://realtime-listings.webservices.zpg.co.uk/certificates/signing_requests/)

Comment: Hi, thanks very much. You're spot on. I'm using Laravel and MAMP on a Mac so 2 things have come to light. I'm going to need to use Homestead so that cUrl will work and I also need to get my server update to CentOS 7. Both of these should put me on the right track so thanks very much